# python text box new line is not working for me

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I created  a simple application containing of buttons  so when the button is clicked  it saves the button name and number of clicks into a `Text`

but my problem is when I click  onother button iT saves on same line of the first  by deleting old one
please how I can fix this problem 
I wanna every button that is  click it to save into a new line

this is code for the receipt

```
def Receipt():
    global txtReceipt
    txtReceipt.delete("1.0", END)
    x = random.randint(10908, 500876)
    randomRef = str(x)
    Receipt_Ref.set("BILL" + randomRef)

    txtReceipt.insert(END, 'Receipt Ref: \t\t\t'+Receipt_Ref.get()+"\t\t"+DateofOrder.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END, 'Items\t\t'+'Quantity\t\t\t'+"Price \n\n")




    if variable ==1:
        txtReceipt.insert(END, str(my_text)+'\t\t'+str(bttn_clicks)+'\t\t\t'+""+str(bttn_clicks*3)+"\n")
    if variable ==2:
        txtReceipt.insert(END, str(my_text)+'\t\t'+str(bttn_clicks)+'\t\t\t'+""+str(bttn_clicks*3)+"\n")
    if variable ==3:
        txtReceipt.insert(END, str(my_text)+'\t\t'+str(bttn_clicks)+'\t\t\t'+""+str(bttn_clicks*3)+"\n")
```

and these are of the function that generating buttons

```
 def readqurec():  
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM qureec ")
    return cur.fetchall()


 def showqurec():
    global button,data2

    data2 = readqurec()
    for index, dat in enumerate(data2):
       button= ttk.Button(master, text=dat[0],command=lambda dat=dat:update_count(dat))
       button.grid(row=index+1, column=0,padx=0, pady=0)
       button_dict[dat] = button
 def update_count(x):
     global bttn_clicks,my_text
     my_text=StringVar()
     for name in data2:
          my_text = button_dict[x].cget('text')

     bttn_clicks += 1
```

thanks all

Comment: You're explicitly deleting everything in the widget before adding a new string. Why are you doing that if you want new text appended?

Comment: @BryanOakley  please can you  show me were I am  making this deleting

Comment: This statement: `txtReceipt.delete("1.0", END)`